# c# loop on group by key

Tags: c#, datatable

I have made a group by statement on a datatable like this:

```
var finalResult = (from r in result.AsEnumerable()
                               group r by new
                               {
                                   r.Agent,
                                   r.Reason
                               } into grp
                               select new
                               {
                                   Agent = grp.Key.Agent,
                                   Reason = grp.Key.Reason,
                                   Count = grp.Count()
                               }).ToList();
```

The `finalResult` will be like this:

```
agent1    reason1    4
agent1    reason2    7
agent2    reason1    8
agent2    reason2    3
..
...
...
agentn   reason1    3
agentn   reason2    11
```

I want to loop over agent name in order to get the reasons and the counts for each reason for each agent. **In other words**: i need to build this :

[image]

can you tell me please how to loop over agent name from the `finalResult` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need one more GroupBy and you are done:

```
var solution =
      finalResult
      .GroupBy(x => x.Agent);
foreach (var group in solution)
        {
            // group.Key is the agent
            // All items in group are a sequence of reasons and counts for this agent
            foreach (var item in group)
            {
                // Item has <Agent, Reason, Count> and belongs to the agent from group.Key
            }
        }
```

Outer loop goes over all the agents (so Agent1, Agent2, etc.) while inner loop will go through all reasons for the *current* agent.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try GroupBy in LINQ :

You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
var agentGroups = finalResult
    .GroupBy(x => x.Agent)
    .Select(ag => new
    {
        Agent = ag.Key,
        ReasonCounts = ag.GroupBy(x => x.Reason)
                         .Select(g => new
                         {
                             Agent = ag.Key,
                             Reason = g.Key,
                             Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count)
                         }).ToList(),
        Total_Count = ag.Sum(x => x.Count)
    });
foreach (var agentGroup in agentGroups)
{
    string agent = agentGroup.Agent;
    int totalCount = agentGroup.Total_Count;
    foreach (var reasonCount in agentGroup.ReasonCounts)
    {
        string reason = reasonCount.Reason;
        int count = reasonCount.Count;
    }
}
```